# Angular2 popup update

Tags: angular

I have a popup page that has header, content and footer.
The content has user info like fname,lname,email,phone...etc.
When I click on profile page a popup will be shown and the details can be updated by clicking update button.

I am handling the update in my component. In my component i am not able to get the form data from the form after submit.

I used form builder in my component and @Output Eventemiiter to handle the form data. But unable to get the data in my update method. \

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user)"`

Comment: Thanks for the response anshuVersatile. But the form submission is happening on button click from popup. So the form data is not being bound in the component.